# Any way to override JavaScript's default confirm function to synchronously block later JavaScript without writing a callback?

Tags: javascript, confirm

I have a very large code base with the JavaScript confirm function appearing all over it.  In order to make it easier for my customers, I have written a Chrome Extension which embeds my tool into another website using iFrames.  (The customers have to install this Chrome Extension, and we work closely with the other software; nothing is secret or nefarious here.)

Thanks to [the latest Chromium change, confirms no longer work inside of iFrames](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5148698084376576), which is driving a lot of customer confusion.  I'm forced with replacing all of them in the code base with a modal.

Since confirm previously blocked the next line of JavaScript from executing until the user picks an option, the code is frequently things like the following:

```
    jQuery('form').submit(function() {
        var sure = confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the form?");
        return sure;
    });
```

Is there a way I can re-write this in one place (i.e. a plugin which simulates the functionality) without having to touch 100s of places in the code?  Or if I do have to make 100s of changes, is there any way to make the implementation simple, so each one doesn't need specific handling?

Or am I just screwed?

Comment: Could you just override confirm with your own function at the top level of your tool?

`window.confirm = (message) => /* new logic */ console.log(message)`

Comment: An extension should be able to provide the iframe with access to the parent-window `confirm` function, which still works. But yeah, you should eventually rewrite all of your code to support proper asynchronous dialog elements.

Comment: @wegry That doesn't handle the blocking nature of confirm which we were using to confirm the form submissions INSIDE the iFrame though.

Comment: @Bergi How would I be able to trigger this on the parent with an extension?  I've been using postMessage to ferry data, but obviously that's not blocking, and I need to block to get the response from the user before submitting the form.

Comment: @Bing You say you're embedding your tool by using an iframe. However, with a browser extension, you should be able to embed the tool directly into the page, circumventing any SOP (and eliminating the need to use `postMessage`). If rendering the content is an issue, you might still use an iframe but make the browser believe that the code for it comes from the same domain.

Comment: @Bergi _but make the browser believe that the code for it comes from the same domain_ -- Do you know how I would do this?  It would solve a lot of these problems.

Comment: I don't know how complicated your tool is or what it does, but I thought of creating an iframe, with any page from the current domain, then overwriting its HTML with that of your tool. The best option might be completely dropping the iframe though, and just putting your tool right in the DOM of the page where it should show up.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds impossible, unfortunately, because:

1. You want to make it synchronous, which means *nothing* can run on the main thread while the modal is open, and
2. You want the browser to render the modal and to know when the user wants to close it.

Since HTML rendering happens on the main thread, the only way the browser could ever render the modal is if the `confirm()` function returns (or throws) and the call stack empties. Event handlers suffer from the same issue.

I'm not sure if there's a way to solve this with extensions (my guess is that there isn't), but either way, an HTML modal is not the way to go.

Comment: Unfortunately the Chromium devs themselves told me the modal was the ONLY option now since they're eventually planning on phasing out alert/confirm/prompt completely, not even for native sites.

Comment: I have an idea here: overwrite the confirm function with one that returns false and renders the modal.  It applies a callback function to the "yes" button which, if clicked, sets a global variable to true and re-runs the stack trace that built it (this is the tricky part, would use `Function.caller` or `arguments.callee.caller`).  I've got it all working except one issue (will post once handled) where the call stack just seems to stop executing when it hits itself again.